# call api on local server in flutter

Tags: api, flutter

this is my code to get data from api in flutter but I received statuscode: 400!!!
please help.

```
void getProductList(String action, List<Product> list) async  {
   if (list.length == 0) {
      var url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/product";
      final http.Response response= await http.get(url);
      print(response.statusCode);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          List jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
          for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
            setState(() {
              list.add(new Product(title: jsonResponse[i]['title'],
                  img_url: jsonResponse[i]['img_url'],
                  price: int.parse(jsonResponse[i]['price'])));
            });
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is in the logs of your local server? Could you update your post with them to maybe help us out?

Comment: Is your local server running on your laptop or PC?

Comment: make sure that your service is running, make sure your endpoint supports the method you called (http get), 400 means bad request

Comment: This is probably a serverside issue, try to look through that code.

Comment: I run an api designed in asp.net and run it in visual studio by iis express so I get response in postman. how can I run it on iis?

Comment: I worked on IIS and found out that the status code 400 launched by my program was because of IIS but now it launches status code 500. in fact the main page is loaded in iis but I dont know how to reach my api to get the answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

try requesting another endpoint to see if the problem is in your local server, try this:

```
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
      final response= await http.get(url);
      print(response.statusCode);
```

if it worked then the problem is server-side.

#### Old Answer

If it's giving you StatusCode 400 then it means that the server is working fine, so probably the problem is in the request itself, try adding headers to your request.

```
 await http.get(url, headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  'Accept': 'application/json'
 }, 
);
```

if this was not the issue, can you please add the error message!

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but it did not work yet please see the error: I/flutter ( 8051): 400
I/flutter ( 8051): 400

Comment: I/flutter ( 8051): 400
I/chatty  ( 8051): uid=10090(mystore.my_store) Thread-2 identical 2 lines
I/flutter ( 8051): 400

Comment: Can you kindly add it to your question ? also check the updated answer.